# data.table foverlaps with as.yearmon wrong result

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to use `foverlaps` from the `data.table` package. When I use it together with `as.yearmon` I get wrong results. Here is a small example:

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)

x<-data.table(date_lower = c("2009-01","2009-10","2010-10"),date_upper =  c("2009-01","2009-10","2010-10"),event_id = c("1","2","3"))
y<-data.table(date_lower = c("2009-01","2009-03"),date_upper = c("2009-02","2009-04"))

x[,date_lower:=as.yearmon(date_lower)]
x[,date_upper:=as.yearmon(date_upper)]
y[,date_lower:=as.yearmon(date_lower)]
y[,date_upper:=as.yearmon(date_upper)]

setkey(y,date_lower,date_upper)
foverlaps(x,y,type = "within") #wrong result


x[,date_lower:=as.Date(as.yearmon(date_lower))]
x[,date_upper:=as.Date(as.yearmon(date_upper))]
y[,date_lower:=as.Date(as.yearmon(date_lower))]
y[,date_upper:=as.Date(as.yearmon(date_upper))]
setkey(y,date_lower,date_upper)
foverlaps(x,y,type = "within") #looks fine
```

Can somebody explain why when I just use `as.yearmon` I get wrong matches.

Comment: Interesting. It works on a non-equi join (as opposed to `foverlaps`). Naming aside, the values are correct using `yearmon` with `x[y, c("i.date_lower", "i.date_upper") := .(i.date_lower, i.date_upper), on = .(date_lower >= date_lower, date_upper <= date_upper)]`.